# How to separate the string into 3 bases long?

Tags: r

I have some DNA sequences data which are in fasta file. And how can I separate the string into 3 bases long?
I have a code like this

```
codons <- strsplit(k, "(?<=.{3})", perl=T)
```

but it cause an

```
Error in .local(pattern, subject, max.mismatch, min.mismatch, with.indels,  : unused argument (perl = TRUE)
```

How can I adjust it? Thank you
For example

```
> introna[[1]]
69-letter "DNAString" instance
seq: GTAATTTTGGTTTCAATTTCAATTTCCCGACCACTTCTCAATATTCCAACAGATTTCATCCATTGCCAG 
#ideal result
"GTA""ATT""TTG""GTT""TCA""ATT""TCA"......"CAG"
```

Comment: Please provide example data and desired output.

Comment: @AndreElrico I have added the example. Thank you for reminding

Comment: Just for future reference, use `Biostrings::oligonucleotideFrequency(DNAstring, width=3, step=3)`

Comment: @CPak thank you for your answer ：）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're almost there, `strsplit` cannot use lookaround but you can use them in `gsub` to put a certain character (for example "_") in between the codons and then use that to split:

```
strsplit(gsub("(.{3})", "\\1_", k, perl=TRUE), "_")
#[[1]]
# [1] "GTA" "ATT" "TTG" "GTT" "TCA" "ATT" "TCA" "ATT" "TCC" "CGA" "CCA" "CTT" "CTC" "AAT" "ATT" "CCA" "ACA" "GAT" "TTC" "ATC" "CAT" "TGC" "CAG"
```

Comment: Your answer works thank you so much. Can you explain what is gsub("(.{3})" and "\\1_"means? I just know gsub is using for matching patterns.

Comment: I put the pattern in between bracket to capture it, I then retrieve it with `\\1` (as it's the first pattern in between brackets) in the replacement part, followed by an underscore. (You can try `sub("(a)(b)", "\\1_\\2", "ab")` to test it with a more trivial example)

Comment: Oh I got your idea, it is so smart thank you have a nice day : )